# CSS3 animations that should reveal hidden element when hovering parent? (Possible Angular solution)

Tags: html, angularjs, css, css-transitions

I have an Angular app with some buttons that change color on click depending on if they are clicked or not.

```
<div class="filter ng-click="seeButton()">
   <div class="filter-icon'"></div>
   <div class="filter-hover">
       <span class="filter-text">Se</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, I have a designer who likes some animations on websites.

I want the div class `filter-hover` to reveal itself when hovering the parent element `filter`. It should reveal itself from the bottom up. It is located in the bottom of the div and the `filter-hover` should stay at the bottom of the div. I use Angular and it is possible for me to use `angular-animate`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use this selector: `.filter:hover .filter-hover` in CSS or JS to do what you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's give you a quick CSS class. if element `a` is right next to element `b` like this:

```
<a id="a"></a>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You can use `#a:hover + #b`. If `b` is a descendent to `a` like this:

```
<a id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</a>
```

You can use `#a:hover #b`. If there are elements between `a` and `b` but they are in the same scope:

```
<a id="a"></a>
<a></a>
<ol></ol>
<h1></h1>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You can use  `#a:hover ~ #b`.

In your case you will use `#a:hover #b` like this:

```css
.filter-hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.filter:hover .filter-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.filter {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter" ng-click="seeButton()">
  <div class="filter-icon'"></div>
  <div class="filter-hover">
    <span class="filter-text">Se</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know my question was pretty badly explained, but this actually help me a lot to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zbL3ve9a/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:tomato;
}
#child{
    width:50px;height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:none;
}
#parent:hover #child{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like use this technique http://jsfiddle.net/ps5nkpL5/1/ to simply show am element growing or animating from a direction. There are better techniques with javascript, but for with just css, this is what I would do.

```
.filter{
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #dedede;
    position: relative;

}
.filter-hover{
    //background: #f1f1f1;
    text-align:center;
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:75px;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
}
.button{
    background: #252525;
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:-40px;
}
.filter:hover .filter-hover .button{
    bottom: 0px;
    -webkit-transition:  .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
```